# Django mongoengine rendring pdf file

Tags: python-3.x, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to open my pdf file from my search result as i am using mongoengine in django. Recently i shift from sql to mongodb.

how to open pdf file from frontend mongoengine django

search.html for sql db.below code is for sqldb and i am looking for similar to this in mongoengine django

'''

```
<h1>You searched for {{ searched }}  </h1>
    <br/>
    {% for i in Document %}
     <a href="{{ i.file.url }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" target="_blank">
     {{i.filename}}</a>
    <br/>
```

'''

This is my search function

'''

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('searched'):                                       
            searched = request.POST.get('searched')
            dbname = my_client['resume']
            collection_name = dbname["user_resumes"]
            collection_name.create_index([("num2","text")])
            Document = collection_name.find({"$text": {"$search": str(searched)}},{"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}).sort([("score",{"$meta":"textScore"})])   
         return render(request,'search.html'{'searched':searched,'Document':Document})
'''
```

if you have any reference please share it with me.

Comment: It's not super clear what problems you're running into from these snippets.  It would be good to show the issue that occurs with your code, and what you've done to try to fix it.  It's best to focus on a single problem.  If you're having trouble both querying the database and rendering the results, you may need to break them into different questions

Comment: In short i want to Query for binary data(pdf file) - MongoDB using django